# What is a DGT 2010 Limited Edition chess clock worth?

Tags: chess-clocks

I have a DGT 2010 Limited Edition chess clock (red version from 2013) and I want to know the market value.

I can't find any listings for it on ebay or chess shop websites, other than old pages from 2013, and the item is "unavailable".

So what's it worth?

[image: DGT 2010 Limited Edition (Red Color)]

Answer (score 2):

These are still very common, so not worth a lot. Considering that the more recent ["DGT 3000 Limited Edition" clock can be bought for $59.93][1], at least it held its value, but no more. Don't be fooled by "Limited Edition"...it does not equate to "rare".

P.S. Sorry, I did not pickup on the difference...they both looked red to me, but I see it now. Frankly, I still do not think it is going to make it valuable unless you wait many years, but you can do a couple of things to find out what it is really worth now:

1. Put it up for sale on eBay and start high with the price, but if you do, only use a "Buy It Now". If you put it up for bid, you will definitely get a lot less.
2. Set up an eBay search that sends you an email every time there is a new listing. Eventually, someone is sure to be selling one, and you will get an idea of what it is worth when it sells.

Comment: Those are not the same clock. The ones you link to are the "DGT 2010" which is maroon-colored and currently selling on the DGT website for 60 Euros. The one I showed is the "DGT 2010 Limited Edition" which is red-colored and was only sold from January 1st 2013 until December 31st 2013. The only differences are the color and the writing on the face at the bottom right.

Comment: @DGT2010LimitedEdition Sorry, I edited my answer.

Comment: I have one of this which I got repaired yesterday the 5 push tactile buttons and its back in working order now. The limited edition.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth what a willing buyer would pay you. For what it's worth, I would prefer a new clock at the $60 noted above.  For me to even consider buying it the price would have to be  about $10.  And that is assuming it works fine.

You could try listing it on Craigs List for what you are willing to take and see if anyone will buy it.  Or you could try that on ebay with a reserve price.

One thing putting me off is the rocker arm.  If it was the touch button I would be more interested.  But this is just me and a random sample of one.
Other people might value it more.

Comment: The clock that the other answer linked to is not the same. See my comment on that answer.

Comment: @ DGT 2010 Limited Edition   --  I am referring to the one in the picture of the OP.  Still,  I would not be interested in a used clock if new ones with all the fancy features are only $60.  Some people may need to buy a clock cheaply but if they can afford travel and tournament fees that is silly to me.

Comment: @ DGT 2010 Limited Edition  --   and my answer stands as given no matter what the clock.  It is worth what someone is willing to pay you for it.  As phishmaster said just because it is 'limited edition' does not make it worth more.  Many limited editions are limited only by the number that they can sell.  AND the thing is almost ten years old.